# Why use \msg_error:nn(nnnnn) in expl3?

Tags: latex3, programming, error-writing

`expl3` has several kinds of error/warning types that can be issued during execution, in particular:

- `\msg_fatal:nn(nnnn)` halts the execution;
- `\msg_critical:nn(nnnn)` stops scanning the current file;
- `\msg_error:nn(nnnn)` interrupt the TeX run but *doesn't interrupt* it.

I don't understand the benefits of `\msg_error:nn(nnnn)` over `\msg_critical:nn(nnnn)` or `\msg_fatal:nn(nnnn)`: it may seems reasonable to collect as many as errors before quitting in order to give users a more detailed feedback, however usually only the first error issued is meaningful and the followings are just a direct consequence of the first one. In addition forcing TeX to scan the entire document even if the resulting PDF will be surely invalid is just a waste of time.

There are some valid reason to use `\msg_error:nn(nnnn)` over other error message types?

Comment: it is not true that only the first error is meaningful. A document can contain many unrelated small errors. I normally prefer `\msg_error` as it gives me the *choice*  to react to an error depending on the situation. E.g. if I want simply an overview of the problems passing over simple errors are often fine, and if I see something fatal, I can stop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is there because one can imagine different cases. Taking `siunitx` as a starting point

- The number parser might get something it doesn't like (`1.2.3`). That's an error but is localised, and can be handled by issuing an error then continuing: `\msg_error:nn(nnnn)`.
- The version of `expl3` available might be too old: that blocks loading `siunitx` but might not be fatal more widely (a package can be loaded but not used in the document): `\msg_critial:nn(nnnn)`.
- A class might load `siunitx` and explicitly *require* that all units are typeset using `\unit`. If `siunitx` is not available or is too old, that's a blocker: `\msg_fatal:nn(nnnn)`.

Comment: So `\msg_error:nn` should be used when the error only impacts a single part of the package, `\msg_critical:nn` when the error makes the entire package unusable and `\msg_fatal:nn` when the main document is not able to work properly due to that error, right?

Comment: @desio Yes, that would be my model

Answer (score 4):

There are many situations where you may want to give an error but could recover gracefully without triggering a trail of spurious errors from tex's in-built recovery.
It is basically equivalent to `\PackageError` in classic 2e programing.

Consider a missing graphic file: you may want to give an error but can still cleanly skip the graphic inclusion perhaps after typesetting some marker. You don't need to kill the whole run if the user wishes to scroll past.

Answer (score 1):

That's how TeX has been from the very beginning.

After an error message, you're given the opportunity (if running in interactive mode) to attempt recover from the error. A simple typing error of a control sequence name, the usual example is `\hobx` can be recovered by typing

```
I\hbox
```

and hitting the return key. For other errors it may be more difficult, but you're shown where TeX has stopped and in several cases you can remove a number of characters from the input stream by typing in the number and hitting the return key. A “missing `$`” error will produce invalid output, but can most of the time be recovered.

At the time TeX was written, computer time was expensive. You were typically sitting in front of a terminal connected to a mainframe computer and have limited session time. The terminal usually had no graphic capability and could represent the output in a not so friendly way. Therefore catching as many errors as possible during a run was a very important feature.

Nowadays most TeX runs are done via a front-end that usually calls TeX with the `-interaction=nonstopmode` flag. You can also use `-interaction=errorstopmode` so the first error stops the run.

If one is able to read the log file, maybe with the help of some filter program such as `texloganalyser`, several errors can be caught in a single session. I'd not worry about the invalid PDF you get: also error-free runs may produce a wrong result and proofreading is necessary anyway.